# how to add items in uinavigationbar at a specific position?

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem, navigationbar

I am developing one application for iphone and in that i have some issues regarding adding more then one `UILabel` in navigation bar at a specific position.

What i want is in following images

[image]

in above image there is one backbar button and one `imageview` as shown with arrow-mark. Other then that all white box is for difrent `UILabels` to show in navigation bar.
There is only one `UIImageView` in the navigation bar and one left bar button. Now problem is that i don't know how to add multiple `UILabel` in navigation bar at a specific position.

Till now what i have worked is to add only button and `UIImageView` with the right bar button array or left bar button array, but that only add items in sequnce.

So can anyone please guide me that how can anyone add UILabels or any other item at a specific position..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can add Multiple UIlabel or Image as look like bellow image:-

[image]

this can do using bellow code you can change Label and imageView frame and put as your requirement

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    UIView *btn = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 60)];

    UILabel *label;
    label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 25, 200, 16)];
    label.tag = 1;
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
    label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
    label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.text = @"My first lable";
    label.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [btn addSubview:label];
    [label release];

    label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 30, 200, 16)];
    label.tag = 2;
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
    label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
    label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.text = @"second line";
    label.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [btn addSubview:label];
    [label release];


    UIImageView *imgviw=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(170, 10, 20, 20)];
     imgviw.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    imgviw.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"a59117c2eb511d911cbf62cf97a34d56.png"];
     [btn addSubview:imgviw];

    self.navigationItem.titleView = btn;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add subviews directly to the navigationBar -

```
UINavigationBar *navBar = navController.navigationBar;
[navBar addSubview: yourLabel];
```

yourLabel frame origin will be relative to the navigation bar

Comment: awesome, if the issue is closed I'd suggest to accept an answer

Comment: Apple does not recommend directly adding a view as Navigation Bar's subview.

Comment: I agree, they usually prefer not to touch any native controllers. anyway that's just a way to do this :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
UIView *buttonContainer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 44)];
buttonContainer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
UIButton *button0 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
   [button0 setFrame: CGRectMake(160, 7 , 40,  30)];
[button0 setTitle:@"Sort" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button0.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12];
[button0 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Btn_Sort_Btn_Sort_Places.png"]    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button0 addTarget:self action:@selector(sortAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button0 setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];
[buttonContainer addSubview:button0];
self.navigationItem.titleView = buttonContainer;

UILabel *lbl_title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0 , 140, 40)];
lbl_title.text = str_HeaderTitle;
lbl_title.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
lbl_title.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:16];
lbl_title.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
lbl_title.textAlignment   = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[buttonContainer addSubview:lbl_title];
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this piece of code. With some modifications it should solve your problem:

```
UIButton *imageButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[imageButton setFrame:CGRectMake(15, 0, 57, 44)];
[imageButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140, 0, 250, 44)];
[titleLabel setText:@"some title"];
[titleLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[titleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20]];

[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:imageButton];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:titleLabel];
```

Just modify the values in the `CGRectMake()` to fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can set an arbitrary view instead of a view controller's title:

```
myViewController.navigationItem.titleView = someView;
```

Note that most likely the view's frame will be restricted to make room for `leftBarButtonItem` and `rightBarButtonItem`.

Answer (score 1):

```
UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 2, 20, 15)];
[label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

UIImageView *imgView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 20, 150, 10)];
[imgView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

[[self.navigationController navigationBar] addSubview:label];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:imgView];
```