# How to add two buttons to the UINavigation bar title view

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

can any body help me how to add two buttons to the navigation title view by using the title view property. I tried but, able to add only one button by using the following code.

```
UIView *customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
customView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

UIButton *b1 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
UIButton *b2 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];

[b1 setTitle:@"Hai" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[b2 setTitle:@"Hello" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[customView insertSubview:b1 atIndex:0];
[customView insertSubview:b2 atIndex:1];   

self.navigationItem.titleView = customView;
```

Comment: what about this answer of mine try with this you did some minore mistake take a look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16958913/how-to-add-items-in-uinavigationbar-at-a-specific-position/16959449#16959449

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code:

```
UIView *customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 44)];
customView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

UIButton *b1 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
UIButton *b2 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 0, 50, 50)];

[b1 setTitle:@"Hai" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[b2 setTitle:@"Hello" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[customView insertSubview:b1 atIndex:0];
[customView insertSubview:b2 atIndex:1];

self.navigationItem.titleView = customView;
```

Outputs:

[image: Example image of output]

Comment: have you checked my answer ?

Comment: see my edit by inserting subviews i am getting the following exception.

Comment: why -1 ? let me know reason

Comment: -[UIButton isSystemItem] unrecognised selector sent to instance.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have added the same frame for both Buttons. So, the Buttons are actually overlapped. You should use this code instead :

```
UIButton *b1=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
UIButton *b2=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 0, 50, 50)];
```

Then you can simply add these buttons to your custom view.

```
[cusotmView addSubView:b1];
[cusotmView addSubView:b2];
```

---

**Reason for Error :**

You can't directly add `UIButtons`. You need to wrap them as `UIBarButtonItems` first.

**Sample Code :**

```
UIBarButtonItem *btn1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:b1];
UIBarButtonItem *btn2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:b2];
[cusotmView addSubView:btn1];
[cusotmView addSubView:btn2];
```

Comment: i tried your code, but no luck I am getting the exception like -[UIButton isSystemItem] unrecognised selector sent to instance.